# UI Testing NSPredicate for cells staticTexts

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nspredicate, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I'm creating a XCUIElementQuery to get all cells that have staticTexts begin with a string (e.g. "Buy") but have no idea. I googled but no hope.

The desperate attempt get staticText but not cell.

```
    XCUIElementQuery *rows = [app.cells.staticTexts matchingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"label CONTAINS 'Buy'"]];
```

Any one experienced with this? Can we get `parent` of the above staticTexts at least?

Comment: @a developer, do you have dynamic prototype cells or static cells?

Comment: They are dynamic prototype cells.

Answer (score 6):

I've found this works:

```
XCUIElementQuery *rows = 
   [app.cells containingPredicate:
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"label CONTAINS 'Buy'"]];
```

If you use app.cells.staticTexts you are going to get a query of labels not cells.
Also make sure you are on the official Xcode 7. Beta's may have been buggy.